# Receiving updates from the server across all devices

Tags: http, angular

I'm using Angular 2 to send requets to my Laravel PHP API and show them in my client.
So far, I used the following code to check for new updates from the server and update my data (making an API call in interval of 3 seconds):

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.dataRefresh = setInterval(() => {
    this.dataInit(); 
  }, 3000);     
}

dataInit()
{
  this.http.get('APICALL')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.data = data;
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
}
```

Now I'm thinking further. Let's say 50 computers are connected in the same time to my app. Each of them making an API call every 3 seconds, which means the server will have to handle about 16 requests every second.

**My question is:**
Can I handle this scenario using Angular 2 / Laravel?
If no, what's the current way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a real time database like [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

Instead of your clients asking for updates to your API every second, your API will let know the clients when there is any update.

You can find firebase tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD0xYicNcaY) & [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b64E6zPG1cg).

There are also some packages available like [angular2-firebase](https://github.com/OasisDigital/angular2-firebase) and [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) to help your Angular2 app connect to your firebase db easily.

Comment: Cool thank you! I see that Firebase can be integrated with angular2 and also with the server side, Laravel. What's the difference?